# Affine Subspace as a Translation of Vector Space

Tags: affine-geometry, polytopes

How to prove:

An affine subspace $\mathbb{E}^n$ is $S=p+V$ for some $p\in\mathbb{E}^n$ and a vector space $V$ of $\mathbb{E}^n$.

I already tried showing $S-p=\{s - p \mid s \in S\}=V$ is subspace of $\mathbb{E}^n$. But it is hard to show that $V$ is closed under addition.

Comment: Do you mean "affine subspace **of** $\mathbb E^n$" and "vector **sub**space $V$ of $\mathbb E^n$"? What is $\mathbb E^n$? What definition of affine subspace are you using? (the wikipedia definition makes this trivial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space#Affine_subspaces_and_parallelism)

Comment: How do you define affine subspace?

Comment: The definition I'm using is
"The subset a of $\mathbb{E}^n$ is an affine subcspace if it contains each line,
       xy := {(1-a)x + ay | a ∈ $\mathbb{E}^n$},
where x, y ∈ $\mathbb{E}^n$.
@stewbasic

Comment: @ThomasAndrews see the definition I'm using above

Comment: Is $\mathbb E^n$ a vector space?

Comment: Yes, it it. It is the Euclidean space, you can think of it as the $\mathbb{R}^n$. @stewbasic

Answer (score 1):

If $V=S-p$, and $x,y\in V$, then $x+p,y+p$ are in $S$, and thus:

$$m=\frac{1}{2}(x+p)+\frac{1}{2}(y+p)=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)+p\in S$$

But then $$2m+(1-2)p=x+y+2p-p=x+y+p\in S$$

And hence $x+y\in V$.

Similarly, if $x\in V$ and $\lambda$ is a scalar, then $x+p\in S$ and $p\in S$, so $$(1-\lambda)p + \lambda(x+p)=p+\lambda x\in S,$$ so $\lambda x\in V$.

Comment: How are you sure that $1/2 (x+p)$ and $1/2 (y+p)$ is in S?
  @ThomasAndrews

Comment: @ShakiJones We don't, but we know that if $u,v\in S$ then $\frac{1}{2}u+\frac{1}{2}v\in S$.

Answer (score 0):

Strong hint:

Assuming that an affine subspace is a subset $S$ closed under affine combinations, i.e., things of the form $(1-t)u + tv$, where $t \in \Bbb R$ and $u, v \in S$), then this isn't too tough.

Let $p$ be any element of the subspace $S$, and let $Q = \{ v - p \mid v \in S\}$. I'll show $Q$ is a vector subspace.

For $v \in Q$, let's show that $cv \in Q$ (where $c \in \Bbb R$), thus showing closure under scalar multiplication.

Well, $v \in Q$, so there's some $u \in S$ with $u - p = v$. Hence 
$$
cv = cu - cp
$$
which is 
$$
cv = (cu - (c-1)p) - p\\
$$
so all I have to do is show that $h = cu - (c-1)p$ is in $S$, i.e., is an affine combination of two elements of $S$. Well, letting $t = 1-c$, we have $c = 1-t$, so 
$$
h = cu + (1-c) p = (1-t)u + tp
$$
which is an element of $S$ because it's an affine combination of $u$ and $p$, which both are in $S$.

Now all you need to do is try to mimic that to show that $V$ is closed under addition as well.